# Sensitive list in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have VHDL program for a D flip flop as follows

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

ENTITY ff2 IS

  PORT (
    clk   : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    rst_n : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    d     : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    q     : OUT STD_LOGIC
    );

END ff2;

ARCHITECTURE beh OF ff2 IS

BEGIN  -- beh

  ff2_proc: PROCESS (clk, rst_n)
  BEGIN  -- PROCESS ff2_proc
    IF rst_n = '0' THEN     
      q <= '0';
    ELSIF falling_edge(clk) THEN  
      q <= d;
    END IF;
  END PROCESS ff2_proc;

END beh;
```

I don't understand why sensitive list only contains signals clk and rst_n. If I add d signal to sensitive list, what will happen? I hope your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add `d` to the sensitivity list, the simulator will possibly need to do a bit more work, but the output will be identical.

#### That being said...

Let's look at the 3 variables independently, and ask the question: "If this variable changes, could the output of this process change?

- **clk**: Well, if `clk` changes, it's possible that `d` has a new value that we need to store to `q`. So that's necessary.
- **rst_n**: Well, if this changes, we could possibly be setting `q` to 0. So that's necessary.
- **d**: Well, if `d` changes, and nothing else changed, then the output of the process doesn't change. So we don't need this signal in the sensitivity list.

Comment: There's also the appeal to authority, the now lapsed IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 VHDL Register Transfer Level (RTL) Synthesis standard, 6.1.3.1 Edge-sensitive storage from a process with sensitivity list and one clock, see NOTES 1. `Except for a clock signal, signals read in a <sync_assignment> or signals controlling a <sync_assignment> are not required to be on the process sensitivity list.`  Essentially the form of the flip flop is both recognizable for synthesis and functional for simulation.